# How do I prevent mud flow from neighbor's yard around metal fence posts?

Tags: drainage, fence

The neighbor carted in a lot of dirt and raised it about 18" -24" higher than my yard on the other side of the fence. I have a French drain, but the mud from their yard keeps flowing into my yard (2 years now) and covers up my rocks and clogs my drain. My nice rock side yard becomes a muddy mess.  I have put bricks on their side of the fence, under the fence to keep the mud from flowing over my rocks; but, around the fence posts it continues to come in. The neighbors poured small stones along the fence line. This has done nothing since the stones now run into my yard with the mud. They are very nice neighbors and did not do this on purpose, but I need a solution even if I have to do it myself. I am tired of cleaning out the drain. I am getting older and it is becoming more difficult. What can I put around the metal fence posts to keep mud from seeping in around them?

Comment: tell them to put in a proper drainage solution at the boundary that doesn't involve surface water running off into your yard.

Comment: Some places might have rules/regulations about this.  Even nice neighbours are responsible for damage they cause to their neighbours land.  They will need to put in place some type of retaining wall or stabilize their land/dirt.

Comment: Welcome to "sue your [derogatory term] neighbor" since that's actually your only real solution, here. This is not "nice" and is utterly irresponsible behavior on their part. Whether or not the insult to your yard was "intentional" it has happened, and they are responsible for fixing it.

Comment: In our area we are not allowed to change the natural flow of water without going through the proper authorities. You might check with your local inspector to see if a permit is required and if this is actually allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I worked on a similar case. I got a sidewalk scraper/ice scraper for any Northerners out there and cut a 4" deep slit along the length of the fence right up against it. Then rolled out 12" flashing and shoved it into the slit and then stapled the top part of the flashing to the fence. If the fence poles are now the only problem, you could install this just around them and overlap the fence on both sides of the pole.

Naturally, this should be the neighbor's problem but this should work for you if you want to take matters into your own hands.